# converting Scientific notation of a column to decimal value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

I have following data in a column

| value |
| --- |
| 1.873452634567E7 |
| null |
| 1.87345265634544467E9 |
| 1.8734526563456347E10 |
| 1.8734526563456723E8 |

i tried

```
df.withColumn("s", 'value.cast("Decimal(14,4)"))
```

but its not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first cast to float and then Decimal you will get what you need.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("ScientificToDecimal").getOrCreate()

# Sample data
data = [("1.873452634567E7",),
        (None,),
        ("1.87345265634544467E9",),
        ("1.8734526563456347E10",),
        ("1.8734526563456723E8",)]

# Define schema and create a DataFrame
columns = ["value"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

# Convert to float first, then to decimal
df = df.withColumn("value_float", col("value").cast("float"))
df = df.withColumn("value_decimal", col("value_float").cast("Decimal(38,4)"))

# Show results
df.show()
```